# if/else and setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```js
<script>
    
    
    //when user clicks start button this function ensures all fields //are set to 0 and it
    //sets the timer for the game (90seconds) and the second timer to //call showWord() every four seconds to display a new word
   
function startGame() {
    numBadWordsField.innerHTML = '';
    numGoodWordsField.innerHTML = '';
    numWordsRight = 0;
    numWordsWrong = 0;
    correctWords = [];
    showWord();
    gameTimer = setInterval(gameTime, 1000);
    timedWordDisplay = setInterval(showWord, 4000);
    }
    
    
    
    //this function is set to repeat every four seconds unless the user //types the word
    //correctly in which case code in the checkWord() function resets setInterval then and a new word appears 
    
    function showWord() {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*wordsLevelOne.length);
    currentWord = wordsLevelOne[randomNum];
        //i put all correctly typed words in an array to avoid them being repeated
        //if the random word has been typed correctly and is in the array then i tell the
        //program to repeat the function until a new word is found. 
    if (correctWords.includes(currentWord)) {
        showWord();
    } else {
        wordDisplayBox.innerHTML = currentWord;
        setInterval(changeBar, 500);
        answerBox.focus();
    }
   
}
   
    //this function is called oninput as user types in the word. it works perfectly (i think it does anyways) 
    //however i cannot figure out how to give instructions in the event the user does not type the
    //word correctly before the four seconds are up and the setInterval repeats. I would like to 
    //in that case increment the words wrong score and reset the fields to be ready for the next 
    //word to be displayed
    function checkWord() {
    let currentWordLen = answerBox.value.length;
    if (wordDisplayBox.innerHTML === answerBox.value) {
        clearInterval(timedWordDisplay);
        numWordsRight++;
        correctWords.push(currentWord);
        numGoodWordsField.innerHTML = numWordsRight;
        answerBox.value = '';
        answerBox.focus();
        wordDisplayBox.innerHTML = '';
        showWord();
        timedWordDisplay = setInterval(showWord, 4000);
    } else if (answerBox.value === currentWord.substring(0, currentWordLen)) {
             answerBox.style.borderColor = 'green';
    } else  {
             answerBox.style.borderColor = 'red';
    } 
}
 
    
    //different topic than above but i also researched how to make my progress bar fill slowly over the course
    //of the four seconds. i have written the following function identically to that on 
    //w3schools and other code yet it does not work. 
        //Any ideas?
   function changeBar() {
   let proBar = document.querySelector('#progressBar');
    var width = 1;
   var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width++;
        proBar.style.width =  width + '%';
    }
    }
    }
    
    </script>
```

This project Im working on is a beginner level speed typing game that displays a different word for the user to type in less than four seconds.I have a setInterval that displays a different word every four seconds unless the user types the word correctly at which point the timer starts over then. What I am stumped at is how can I make it so that if the correct answer is not typed in before the interval resets (at the end of four seconds) the program knows to increment the 'wrong answer' score and to reset the input boxes for the next word just like when it is typed correctly.  i have attached the parts of my code i think may be relevant. If anyone has any suggestions let me know. I am eager to learn. **I am not familiar yet with JQuery. Please describe any suggestions using vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

This feature should be implemented in the `showWord` function.

`showWord` is executed after 4 seconds have passed, which is when the time is up. Executing this function means the user has failed to type the word in time.

I would do something like this :

```
function showWord() {
  // At this point, the user has lost. We perform the according operations
  numWordsWrong++;
  answerBox.value = '';
  // etc.

  // What follows is the rest of the function you've already implemented
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*wordsLevelOne.length);
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding. i see your point but it added 1 to 'words wrong' every time showWord() was called even if it was a right answer. i tried using an 'if (input != word) but it called showWord() for every keyup. How can I instruct it to "if  answerBox.value != currentWord when the interval for showWord() is reset then do this..." while not affecting the code ran for a correct answer or while user is typing (at keyup). Any thoughts on if it is possible to use a separate timer maybe but how to link that to each function? many thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the progress bar, you are setting an interval to run changeBar every 500 milliseconds, which would cause the progress bar to reset every half second. If you want a delay before starting the progress bar use setTimeout.

In addition, you are running your progress bar to move 1% every 10 milliseconds which would result in the bar completing in 1 second. If you want the bar to complete in 4 seconds, set the id interval to run every 40 milliseconds.

Without seeing your css and html, I have to assume you're using the correct id names in your code but if nothing is happening at all, that could also be the cause.

I have looked at the W3Shools code you reference and I tried to replicate what you were trying to do and got this to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  }

  #myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
  function changeBar() {
   let proBar = document.querySelector('#myBar');
    var width = 1;
   var id = setInterval(frame, 40);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        proBar.style.width =  width + '%';
      }
    }
  }
  setTimeout(changeBar, 100);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to create a new function (ex : `showWordBecauseTimeout`) and call it in your `setInterval` instead of `showWord`. And call that function in `showWord` fct instead of in `startGame` fct.

So the new code would be something like :

```
    function showWord() {
        clearInterval(timedWordDisplay);
        timedWordDisplay = setInterval(showWordBecauseTimeout, 4000);
        // you also need to move the cleaning of the input in the showWord fct
        // ...
    }

    function showWordBecauseTimeout() {
        numWordsWrong++;
        showWord()
    }
```

Hope that it helps you :).